# Android studio - /system/bin/sh: Permission Denied

Tags: android, windows, shell, android-studio

In Android Studio, I want to run my app in my device but I have an error message:

> $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/my.model" /system/bin/sh:
> pm: can't execute: Permission denied

*(It launch perfectly in emulator with 0 error.)*

---

I have a Samsung S3 Mini rooted phone. My phone is visible with command `adb devices`.

I have tried: run Android Studio in administrator, add `ADB` path on environment variable, remove build folder and rebuild project, but I have always this error.

I guess that's why it does not start my Activity.

> $ adb push C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\Model\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
> /data/local/tmp/my.model
>
> $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/my.model"
>
> /system/bin/sh: pm: can't execute: Permission denied
>
> $ adb shell am start -n "my.model/my.model.MainActivity" -a
> android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>
> Error while executing: am start -n "my.model/my.model.MainActivity"
> -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=my.model/.MainActivity }
>
> Error type 3
>
> Error: Activity class {my.model/my.model.MainActivity} does not
> exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

Where is the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found why it is not working. Because pm manager is disabled.

To resolve this issue:

1. Connect your phone to the pc
2. Open a command line and write `adb shell` and press enter
3. Write `su` and press enter
4. Now write `chmod 777 /system/bin/pm`

Enjoy!

Comment: And what if we have `/system/bin/sh: su: can't execute: Permission denied`? I got this when I want to use `su` in Anbox after trying to add a MITM certificate in android.img. I have the same problem if I restore the original snap package. I used the squashfs commands from https://github.com/geeks-r-us/anbox-playstore-installer/commit/3e8082f4861e882e3344c7c6f5c7289a1aa7c336.
Update: I had to use a workaround `sudo anbox.shell` but it would be good to know why `su` stopped working: https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/209#issuecomment-411134146

Answer (score 0):

You do this using adb

adb root (root access)

adb shell (Enter as root)

mount -o rw,remount / (for permission write access)

rm system/app -r Instagram (remove folder)

rm system/app -r Instagram/instagram.apk (remove apk)